# my response stucks i dont get error or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

when i call a get request on redux my call inside of createAsyncThunk stucks i dont get any error or return undefined and my state stays in pending. Also in this code "run1" logs into console but "run2" does not

reducer

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk("getProducts", async () => {
  console.log("run1");
  const data = await axios.get(`localhost:4000/api`);
  console.log("run2");
  return data;
});

export const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: {
    loading: true,
    productsData: [],
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getProducts.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.productsData = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

react file

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, productsData } = useSelector((state) => state.products);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
  }, []);
```

Comment: If "run2" wasn't beeing loged in console, seems like the problem comes from the url, maybe it's inaccesable, or maybe it returns error, try checking `localhost:4000/api`. In the most less possibly case maybe there is something wrong in your axios interceptor part.

Comment: Check the browser console and network tab for errors/issues with the request the app is making. You could complete the thunk by using a `try/catch` and log out the issue as well, even using `thunkApi.rejectWithValue` to pass the error back in the `getProducts.rejected` action payload if you like.

Comment: there is no problem in the url i get the response on browser also postman

Comment: Try to check axios.interceptors.response in your project than

Comment: i dont get any error messages with try catch its still the same case it stucks in the axios call i dont see any activity in network tab of the project but at the server side it returns 200

Comment: So is a GET request being made from your browser to `"localhost:4000/api"`? Can you see that in the network tab? If so, do you get a response back from the server? If so, what is that response?

Comment: yes i get the response which is a json data

Comment: Does a `console.log({ data });` after the request in `getProducts` log the result? Do you see your Redux store get updated? (*You have the Redux-DevTools and extension installed, right?*) So far you haven't shown any code with any issue that would prevent the `getProducts` function from completing.

Comment: no it doesn't log i dont see an update in devtool